# Корректен ли вопрос 'Как сдать ЕГЭ, не ходя в школу?'?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, деепричастный-оборот

Корректен ли вопрос **'Как сдать ЕГЭ, не ходя в школу?'?**
(С точки зрения грамматики и пунктуации.)

[Прим. — Пунктуация в заголовке и в тексте вопроса — авторская. — Р. М.]

Answer (score 1):

**Как сдать ЕГЭ, не ходя в школу?**

Думаю, что предложение корректно.

1) **Форма "ходя" есть в парадигме у Зализняка,** в текстах она также используется.

2) **Обособление зависит от конкретного предложения**

**Оборот не обособляется, если имеет значение наречия,** например: Можно получить среднее образование не ходЯ в школу, в домашних условиях.

Здесь нет паузы, ударение падает только на оборот, однородные отношения с другим обстоятельством.

**Но чаще оборот обособляется, являясь аналогом придаточного обстоятельственного предложения**.

В заданном предложении делается пауза, ударением выделены оба слова (ЕГЭ и не ходя). Оборот имеет обстоятельственное значение условия. Сравнить:  **Как сдать ЕГЭ, если не ходишь в школу?**

Примеры:

Здесь впервые она задумывается: почему отец считает, что можно обходиться без мяса, что можно **молИться,** **не ходЯ в церковь**, что в Библии не все правда, а мама, напротив, делает и утверждает обратное?

Люди, как от этого  **избавиться** **не ходЯ к врачУ** (страховка есть, но беспокоить врача не хочу)? [Красота, здоровье, отдых: Медицина и здоровье (форум) (2005)]

На сие отвечаете вы, что для того, де, от вас отлучаемся, что вы не по старым книгам служите ... что **крестите и венчаете** **не ходЯ по солнцу**. [архиепископ Платон (Левшин). Увещание к раскольникам (1766)]

Answer (score 0):

**А.** Пунктуация,  связанная с собственно оформлением вопроса.

**1.** Кавычки лучше использовать или лапочки (**"..."**), или ёлочки (**«...»**).

В английские одиночные (марровские) кавычки обычно берётся текст, указывающий значение некоторого слова или словосочетания (обычно иноязычного):
"Дама высшего света, обнажавшая лодыжку, бросала обществу XVII в. более сильный вызов, чем сегодняшняя молодая особа, появляющаяся на пляже топлес (от англ. *topless* **‘без верха’**), т. e. в купальном костюме из одной только нижней части".

**2.**  Предложения *Корректен ли вопрос*? и *Как сдать ЕГЭ, не ходя в школу?* вопросительные, поэтому в конце "обобщающего" предложения ставится только один вопросительный знак.

Например: **Помнишь ли ты "А вы смогли бы?"** [В. Маяковский]

**3.** Вопрос может быть оформлен двумя способами.
Корректен ли вопрос: "Как сдать ЕГЭ, не ходя в школу?" (Как прямая речь.)
Корректен ли вопрос "Как сдать ЕГЭ, не ходя в школу?" (Вопрос включен в авторское предложение на правах его компонента.)

**Б.** Корректен ли вопрос?
***Корректный вопрос*** – это вопрос, базис которого является истинным и непротиворечивым знанием.
***Некорректный вопрос*** – это вопрос, предпосылки которого содержат ложные или противоречащие друг другу суждения, или суждения, смысл которых не определен.
[**Б. Л. Яшин. Логика**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=hNnSCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT83&lpg=PT83&dq=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81&source=bl&ots=PwgghrzgVJ&sig=gUcXQH67XR8s7ojnZoUpCcRjMPU&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIq9ufoJrbAhUOr6QKHYqtAcc4ChDoATAEegQIARA9#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81&f=false)

Ваш вопрос "подразумевает" два подвопроса (от смысла "не ходя в школу"):
ни разу не появляясь (не посещая ) школьные занятия (при домашнем обучении?);
если нет возможности посетить школу для сдачи экзамена (ребёнок в данный момент находится в больнице или дома, передвижения противопоказаны).
Этот нюанс необходимо конкретизировать.

**В.** Не ходя = не посещая = не появляясь – я бы поставила запятую (обособление деепричастного оборота).